# Node URL gets "undefined" added to URL path

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, routes

I have a site that exists on a dev, staging and production server. On the dev and staging server the functionality is 100% fine, however on the production server the strangest thing happens - "undefined" gets added to the URL path.

Here is the short example of what is happening:

In the index.html I have an anchor tag to logout of a session with passport: `<a href="auth/logout">Logout</a>`.

It goes to this route on my node server:

```
// passport oauth logout
routes.get('/auth/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy((e) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect(config.redirects.env.prod);
  });
});
```

On dev and staging this destroys the session and redirects you to `/`. On production, when you click the button it takes you to this URL randomly `https://somesite.com/auth/undefined`.

Any ideas on how to debug this? It is making no sense to me and there's nothing I'm finding serverside or in the markup that would cause this, especially since it is functional on dev and staging. All servers are Ubuntu servers set up exactly the same way.

Comment: are your other routes being hit on prod?

Comment: have you logged `config.redirects.env.prod` to make sure it is the proper value?

Comment: @Anselm this is happening with the only other route: https://somesite.com/auth/facebook/callback gets turned into https://somesite.com/auth/facebook/undefined.

Comment: @PatrickEvans can confirm it is the proper value

Comment: Could this be as simple as changing `auth/logout` -> `/auth/logout`

Comment: @Amos47 unfortunately `auth/logout` and `/auth/logout` both have this same problem. Both variations lead to `auth/undefined`.

Comment: Is it possible there's another wildcard route being defined somewhere that is clobbering this route? I'm not sure I completely understand what's happening. Could there also be some middle where doing stuff when you call the req.logout()? Does it work if you remove that?

Comment: There's no wildcard route that would be causing the issue @Amos47. It also occurs for example if you go to site.com/, click the log in to fb button (site.com/auth/facebook), it does its OAuth, then it hits site.com/auth/facebook/callback, somehow that gets mangled and it says it `cannot GET /auth/facebook/undefined`. hit the back button, refresh page, all the social data from facebook that gets parsed in the /auth/facebook/callback route IS THERE. meaning the code in that route ran even tho it says `cannot GET /auth/facebook/undefined`. Just to reiterate this is only on prod, dev/stg are fine.

Comment: Is there a callback link you need to setup in facebook for oauth?

Comment: posted my answer @Amos47 - a very bizarre issue caused by an incredibly simple typo but it was in an unrelated route used for file uploads 400 lines away. Still no clue how the error manifested like this, but all is functional as intended now. Explains why it also only happened on the production server but dev and staging were fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. Oddly enough, 400 lines down in a completely unrelated route used for file uploads, I had a line of code that referenced `config.redirects.env.production` instead of `config.redirects.env.prod`. I wasn't even looking at that route because it wasn't even part of functionality i was testing at the moment and I saw no errors spit out (again, since the route wasnt being referenced/used yet).

Fixing that typo resolved this bizarre issue of "undefined" being inserted into the URL. Still not sure how it managed to bubble up like that.